# Setting a value for global variable in view that can be used in Controller Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

I am a beginner of Laravel. I reading the discussions on implementing global variables. But in my case, I want to set the value of the global variable from the view that can be used in the controller.

My sample code in button from adminHome.blade.php

```
<!--CAMPUS BUTTON-->

                        @foreach($campuses as $campus)
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="card card-user box">
                                <div class="image" style="background-color:#00D27F;"></div>
                                <div class="content bg">
                                    <div class="author">
                                        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
                                        <img class="" src="{{ asset('images/icon-school.png') }}" alt="..."/><br><br><br>
                                          <h4 class="title"><b>{{$campus->campus_name}} Campus</b></h4>

            {{--SOMEWHERE HERE I'LL SET THE VALUE OF THE GLOBAL VARIABLE. THE VALUE I SHOULD SET IS {{$campus->id}}--}}

                                            <h5>{{$campus->name}} Campus</h5>

                                        <hr>
                                        <h5 class="title text-center"> 

                                        </h5>
                                          <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">
                                                <p>VIEW</p>
                                          </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
```

As my code shown above, when I click that button, it would also set the value of the global variable so that in order to proceed on the next page, all the data related on that campus will only be shown. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May I got your Point@ 
there have no way to access variable from view to controller. 
you can put variable in session. so that you can use from anywhere.

```
session(['your_key' => 'your_value']);
```

Comment: can I also use that in where query like this `$assignments = Assignment::join('areas', 'assignments.area_id','=', 'areas.id') ->where('areas.campus_id', '=', session(['variable' => $campus->id]))->get();` ?

Comment: Yes you can.but no need to write here like this. you assign session in View, so just retrieve value from session. Like this      
$assignments = Assignment::join('areas', 'assignments.area_id','=', 'areas.id') ->where('areas.campus_id', '=', session('variable'))->get();
Take a look here  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

Comment: this is how I assign the variable in views `<a href="{{ route('dashboard'), [$request->session()->put('variable', '$campus->id')]}}"> <p>VIEW</p></a>` in my blade view.. am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is when the user presses `VIEW` it opens the campus details yes?

In that case you can do:

```
{{ route('dashboard',['campus_id' => $campus->id]) }}
```

You are using a named route `dashboard` and you can pass in vars to that route with the above code.

Source: [Laravel Named Routes Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#rnamed-routes)

Comment: in that way can I also use campus_id in other views or I mean in a controller, for example I can use the campus_id in a collectionscontroller in collections.index so that the values will show is only for that specified campus?

Comment: Ok with what you have just said it sounds like you would be better storing the ID in a session so that you can access it when you want to. 

Do you need every single campus_id available on other views? or just the one at a time?

Comment: I need it on the other views

Comment: I been studying about storing in a sessions and figuring out how to implement it

Comment: Ok, you can store in a session like so : `session(['variable' => $campus->id])` then in other views or even controllers you can do: `if(session()->has('variable')){ $id = session('variable')}else{dd("Session variable not set");}`

Comment: Okay I'll try that one

Comment: usually i'll just set the value in the view and i'll use that in most of my controller for my queries specifically in where query for example DBname::where(campus_id, =, $campus->id)

Comment: I'll set the session(['variable' => $campus->id]) in the view like this `<a href="{{ route('dashboard'), session(['variable' => $campus->id]) }}">`. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

You could either create and submit a form that will store the value in the back-end, in a database for example and later send the variable to the next view `return view( 'next_page', ['variable' => $campus_id] );`.

Or, you could just get the value from the form with some JS or jQuery magic and use `GET` variables to send it to the next page. `http://example.com/next-page?variable=campus_id` and echo it with `{{ $_GET['variable'] }}`